# Convert All Reference Variables to Pointer Variables

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello I'm a beginner C++ Student and I can't figure out how to do this. I didn't put up the code I was working on because it is very similar to what we started with below. I can't figure out what to do with the string variables in getTimeFromUser function or much of anything else. Below is a description of what we need to do and the original code I wrote using reference operators.

In this coding assignment we are supposed to rewrite this code using pointers(no Reference operators). It requires use pointers for all variables that we have deﬁned except for those in the structure (hours, minutes, and seconds). We aren't supposed to completely rewrite it, just change the thing necessary to use pointers instead of reference operators.

Some of the things listed we should use are:
1: you MUST switch all variables except for those inside the structure to pointers.

2: you dynamically allocate memory using the new operator. Since 
you cannot use the reference operator, you will have to use the new operator.

3: you have to make sure that you de-allocate the memory once you do not need the variable 
anymore. This can be done using the delete function.

4:When you have a structure pointer (e.g. Time* startTime), do not use (.) operator to 
access its member variables. e.g. You need to modify startTime.hours.

5:Similar to the previous point, if you have a string pointer (e.g. string* tmpStr), do not 
use (.) operator to access its member functions. e.g. You need to modify 
tmpStr.length().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Time
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
    Time()
    {
            hour=0;
            minute=0;
            second=0;
    }

};


void getTimeFromUser(Time &value)
{
    string fill, fille, filler;

    getline(cin, fill, ':');

    value.hour = atoi(fill.c_str());

    getline(cin, fille, ':');
    value.minute = atoi(fille.c_str());

    getline(cin, filler);

    value.second = atoi(filler.c_str());

}

void print24Hour(Time a)
{
    if(a.hour <=9)
    {
            cout<<setfill('0')<< setw(2);
    }

    cout<<a.hour<<":";


    if (a.minute <=9)
    {
            cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2);
    }

    cout<<a.minute<<":";


    if(a.second <=9)
    {
            cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2);
    }
    cout<<a.second<< endl;

}

int main()
{
    Time value;
    cout<<"Please enter the time of your course. HH:MM:SS" << endl;

    getTimeFromUser(value);
    cout<<"Your start time is ";
    print24Hour(value);
    cout<<"Please enter your end time"<< endl;
    getTimeFromUser(value);
    cout<<"Your end time is ";
    print24Hour(value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your attempt anyway as an addendum to the question in a separate listing. And I can think of reasons to use dynamic allocation, *none* of which are needed for this assignment. So if you find the assignment pointless you're not alone.

Comment: just when you thought you'd seen the worst possible school C++ assignment stipulations...

Answer (score 0):

They want you to replace

```
string fill;
```

with

```
string *fill = new string;
```

and then wherever you had `fill` after that, change to `(*fill)`.

This is a competely and utterly stupid thing to do BTW. Once you have finished this assignment you should try and forget everything you "learned".